# Unable to run php artisan migrate in a php-apache docker container

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, docker

I am currently using the php-apache image to deploy a laravel application. I tried installing php-mysql extension but it seeems this extension is not available. Whenever I enter `php artisan migrate` in the container this is what I get.
[image: Error page]

This is what my Dockerfile lookslike

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

RUN apt update \
        && apt install -y \
            g++ \
            libicu-dev \
            libpq-dev \
            libzip-dev \
            zip \
            zlib1g-dev \
        && docker-php-ext-install \
            intl \
            opcache \
            pdo \
   


WORKDIR /var/www/laravel_docker

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# RUN ls -la /usr/local/etc/php/
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version : "3.8"
services: 
  mysql_ast:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true #enables shell like interface
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_USER=laraveldb
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123
      - MYSQL_USER=laraveldb
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=db

    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql

  php-apache:
    container_name: php-apache
    build:
      context: ./php
    ports:
        - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/laravel_docker
      - ./apache/default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
      - ./php-ini/php.ini-production:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production
    depends_on:
      - mysql_ast
  
  # myXampp:
  #   container_name: myXampp
  #   image: tomsik68/xampp:8
  #   ports:
  #     - '41061:80'
  #     - '41062:22'
    
  #   volumes: 
  #     - '~my_web_pages:/var/www'
```

.env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:hl1SMrNEf39eHjRTGQegFFUvFJoQPvj0qzC670NwIAA=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db
DB_USERNAME=laraveldb
DB_PASSWORD=123

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
UID=1000
```

**[EDIT]**
This is the php.ini-production file that contains a list of installations.
[image]
It is worth mentioning that the application works well when I start the server via `php artisan serve`. However, I'm unable to run migrations.

Comment: Should the DB_HOST variable be the name of the container, `mysql`, instead of the name of the database, `db`?

Comment: you may need to also install the mysqli (and/or mysqlnd) extension(s)

Comment: @AldenW. I just tried it. Same outcome.

Comment: @apokryfos I already have.

Comment: I think you are missing pdo-mysql in your docker extensions

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you're installing the mysqli extension in what you've shared. PDO itself is an abstraction layer and does need the corresponding database extension to work

Comment: @apokryfos I didn't declare it in the docker file. However, I installed it inside the container via bash. I've edited my question to show what my php.ini-production file looks like. It shows all installed and activated extensions.

Comment: @ArifulIslam. I installed it post-build via bash. See the edit on the question that shows all installed and activated extensions.

Comment: `php.ini-production` is not what is used. You should rename that to `php.ini` to ensure that is the one being read

Comment: @apokryfos will do.